# Variables declared inside the function scope causes if statement an error

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, var

So I declare two variables inside a callback function in if statement `var message` and `var body` now when I run the code, I get error when if statement hits `else` statement and then it throws out `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>`
When I remove `var` keyword from declarations and declare them globally, I get no errors. What is the problem? I tho javascript is function scope language, not block scope. Even declaring them variables outside if statement on the top of the function doesn't help.

Code:

```
function clickBtn() {
  var btn = document.getElementById("button");
  btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (theName.value == "") {
      var message = document.createElement("p");
      message.className = "message";
      message.innerHTML = "You forgot the name and email";
      var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
      body.appendChild(message);
    } else {

    message.parentNode.removeChild(message);
    var user1 = new User (theName.value, theEmail.value);
    users.push(user1);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(users, null, 2));
  }
    theName.value = "";
    theEmail.value = "";
  });
}
clickBtn();
```

Comment: What is `theName`? Please show that code too!

Comment: Can you show the code when you say the problem doesn't happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only assign something to `message` when the `if` value is `true`.

The `else` branch only ever has an undefined value of `message`, which is why you are getting this error.

You can fix this by declaring the `message` variable to have a value outside of the `if/else` statements.

---

Seems that you want to *add* the messages in the `if` and *remove* them in the `else` - to do that, you need to be able to get **the same message**. What you are doing is creating **a new message** every time.

Here is an example of what you can do (based on your code):

```
function clickBtn() {
  var btn = document.getElementById("button");
  btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (theName.value == "") {
      var message = document.createElement("p");
      message.className = "message";
      message.innerHTML = "You forgot the name and email";
      var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
      body.appendChild(message);
    } else {
      message = document.getElementsByClassName("message")[0]; // first one
      message.parentNode.removeChild(message);
      var user1 = new User (theName.value, theEmail.value);
      users.push(user1);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(users, null, 2));
  }
    theName.value = "";
    theEmail.value = "";
  });
}
clickBtn();
```

Comment: `btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var message = document.createElement("p");
    message.className = "message";
    message.innerHTML = "You forgot the name and email";
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    if (theName.value == "") {
      body.appendChild(message);
    } else {
    message.parentNode.removeChild(message);`
I changed it, but now i get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> `

Comment: @Limpuls - you only attach the `message` to the DOM in your `if` clause - you expect it to have parent nodes if you do not attach it to anything?

Comment: what to do then? I need to attach it only when input is empty and when user types in something, then remove the attachment. I don't see how I can attach it all the time without showing the actual innerHTML message in if statement case, or can I?

Comment: @Limpuls - you only detach/remove if it _has_ a `parentNode`: `if(message.parentNode) { message.parentNode.removeChild(message) }`. Fact it, if it isn't there, you haven't added it.

Comment: I did this `var btn = document.getElementById("button");
  btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var message = document.createElement("p");
    message.className = "message";
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.appendChild(message);
    if (theName.value == "") {
      message.innerHTML = "You forgot the name and email";
    } else {
      message.parentNode.removeChild(message);`
I mean it's working when you refresh the page after either if or else statmenet but in the same session it doesn't work. Message stays here even after user types in

Comment: Well, you are creating **new** messages every time. If you need to *remove* messages, you need to find the already attached ones and remove those (add a class to your messages when you create them, find that class to remove them).

Comment: in your code `message.parentNode.removeChild(message);` what is the parentNode of the `message`? `<p>` tag? And why you are not using `var` keyword in else statement for `message`?

Comment: @Limpuls - the `var` is not required, but won't hurt. The parent node would be the one you originally attached the message to (the body). The code is not fool proof (doesn't check if a message was even added at all).

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the variable if the if statement is true but refer to it if it is false. Declare var message=... before the if statement instead and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

> I tho javascript is function scope language, not block scope

The modern code looks a little differently and aims at the functional style and an immutabeleness. With the ES-262 from version 6 is also higher it is desirable to use only const and let, and for future compatibility with ES modules directly to include the use strict mode.
After entering of such corrections into a code, the error from runtime of a phase will pass most likely into compile time a phase. Also instead of use of global information fields, it is better to address the functional closings if such need is.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a concept of variable [hoisting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp).
Javascript is indeed function scoped language, not block scoped.
In your case both `var message` and `var body` get hoisted to the top of the function without being assigned any value(Therefore having a value of undefined).

It is assigned a value only in the if block and is undefined for the else block.

"No var" will look up the scope chain until it finds the variable or hits the global scope (at which point it will create it). When you remove var keyword from declarations, `var message` and `var body` are declared globally and also assigned a value as provided in the assignment. Therefore it does not throw an error.

Declaring these variables in the global scope without assigning any value to them results in `var message` and `var body` being undefined until explicitly assigned a value. And therefore else part throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct about variable being function scope not block scope. However, Javascript will only assign value to your variable when the assignment instruction is reached. In you case you put assignment instruction (`message = document.createElement("p");`) inside if which means that this instruction will not be executed when condition is not met. And Javascript is hoisted, which means that **it moves all declaration (and only declaration)** of variables to the top of the function. So the declaration of `message` is moved to the top of the function and remains `undefined`, and when you try to access `.parentNode` you will get error because `undefined` doesn't have property. Check this out for more details: https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript